# XslCompiledTransform with XSLT 1.0 ms:format-time() Timezone

Tags: asp.net-4.0, xslt-1.0

I am working with an `XslCompiledTransform` object and try to parse a `DateTime` object. It works **but** only shows the GMT date.
When I debug the code, the object has the correct value (GMT+2)

I am using this in the XSLT:

```
ms:format-time(order/@orderDate, 'H:m', 'NL-nl')
```

The output has a two hour difference with the correct value.
Can this be solved using XSLT 1.0 and the default .Net 4 framework methods. (C#)

**Edit:** Can this be solved without adding code to the XSLT https://groups.google.com/d/topic/microsoft.public.xsl/1mPHhh6F62o/discussion

**Edit2:** Seems that more people have problems with formatting time in XSLT 1 With different timezones: http://forums.tizag.com/showthread.php?t=17429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here it the top of my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes"
            xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
    <xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
    <ms:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <![CDATA[              
         public string correctTime(DateTime dt)
         {
            return dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("HH:mm");
         }
    ]]>
    </ms:script>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    ...
```

and further down the XSLT some HTML markup and using the method mentioned above:

```
<tr>
    <td>Tijd:</td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="user:correctTime(order/@datum)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Holland has now (because of daylight saving time) GMT + 2
without the use of this method it just converted my value to GMT
So there was a 2 hour difference. The 1 hour difference we had before wasn't noticed. But because it is now 2 hour, it got to our attention :)